# error handling strategies for biztalk project

Tags: biztalk

i'm wonder if there is any good error handling strategies for biztalk project? and how many is there that i can choose between? example using ESB Toolkit, logging all the error to file or sending to mail.

all tips is thankful and it would be great if there is a lite describe about the strategy or link to a blogger or article about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific? You can implement try-catch logic and inside of catch block you can call external .NET assemblies, which means you can do almost anything to handle your errors. Are you asking about what Biztalk server can do with handled errors or how to implement specific error handling logic?

Comment: i'm asking for tips about how can i handle the error in biztalk. how many way can i handle the error in biztalk? witch mean like logging the errors on file or send the error to my mail. an example of how i can handle errors in biztalk is sending all the errors to the mail and the developer get a notification about the error and he taking care of it or resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, there is a distinction between 'error handling' and 'notification'.

Error handling is implemented using the same patterns you would use in any .Net application.  Scopes with Exception Blocks are analogous to Try...Catch in C#.

Notification is where you have a lot of options.  But, before considering how, you need to define the what.  Meaning what exactly do the users or administrators need to know?  Figure that out, then choose the tools that let you implement to that requirement.

In order of complexity:

- Windows Event Log
- Failed Message Routing
- BizTalk 360
- Custom notification such as e-mail
- Microsoft System Center with the BizTalk Management Pack
- ESB Toolkit Portal
- SharePoint with custom Message Repair and Resubmit

Comment: thanks! could you give me some tips that's use for error handling? what a know is biztalk360 is not use for error handling only for monitoring

Comment: Monitoring is a different subject entirely, but BizTalk 360 does handle notifications.  Not sure what you're asking, there isn't really much to error handling, you just do it.